# Download music from youtube with batch file

Tags: bash, youtube, mp3, youtube-dl

I made a script for downloading music from Youtube using youtube-dl. It worked fine until an update of some kind.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p ' Title : ' title

read -p 'Artist : ' artist

read -p ' Album : ' album

read -p ' Genre : ' genre

youtube-dl "$1" --quiet --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --audio-quality 3 --embed-thumbnail --exec 'mp3gain -q -r -c -s i {} > /dev/null & echo -n {}' | xargs -0  mid3v2 -t "$title" -a "$artist" -A "$album" -g "$genre"

echo --- DONE! ---
```

My beleive is that it is the mp3gain program that is causing the problem and I don't really care about it. I've tried to change the --exec line to:
--exec mid3v2 -t "$title" -a "$artist" -A "$album" -g "$genre"
with no luck.

I liked it because with the command:
"download.bat youtube-url"
I got an mp3 with the sound and a thumbnail.
How could I make a change for it to work?

Comment: Please take note of the tag descriptions before applying them to your posts. The `batch-file` tag does not apply to `bash`.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost close. Would you please change the `youtube-dl` line as:

```
youtube-dl "$1" --quiet --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --audio-quality 3 --embed-thumbnail --exec 'mp3gain -q -r -c -s i {} > /dev/null 2>&1 && printf "%s\0" {}' | xargs -0 mid3v2 -t "$title" -a "$artist" -A "$album" -g "$genre"
```

- `mp3gain` outputs some messages via stderr. You will need to suppress
  them with `2>&1`.
- It is a good practice to add `-0` option to `xargs`. Then you need to
  terminate the filename with a null character.